# Radicals: $\sqrt{\sum_k I^{n_k}_k}\supset \sum_k I_k$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Is it true that given ideals $I_1,\dots ,I_n$ of a commutative ring we have $\sqrt{\sum_k I^{n_k}_k}\supset \sum_k I_k$? How can I prove this?

I think I can manage if the identity $\sqrt{I^m}=\sqrt I$ is true. But this seems strange to me. The inclusion $\sqrt{I^m}\subset \sqrt I$ follows from monotonicity, but tells us that if $r^n\in I^m$ for some $n$ then $r^k\in I$ for some $k$. This seems counter intuitive. For the opposite inclusion $\sqrt{I^m}\supset \sqrt I$, if $r^k\in I$ then $(r^k)^m\in I^m$. Is my proof correct?

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: @Crostul that's good, but it doesn't really make sense to me. I'd have thought you can definitely have situations with $r^n\in I^m$ without any power of $r$ in $I$. Could you provide some intuition?

Comment: @Exterior This is not possible. Recall that $I^m \subset I$, so if $r^n \in I^m$, then $r^n \in I$.

Comment: @Crostul ah, right. Thanks!

Comment: @user26857 it looks like there's an identity $\sqrt{\sum_k \sqrt{I_k}}=\sqrt{\sum_k I_k}$ hiding there. Is this true?

Comment: Maybe you can understand better all of this if you define the radical of $I$ as the intersection of prime ideals containing $I$. Since intersection of ideals and sum of ideals distribute, you can see that all of this is quite natural.

Comment: @Crostul if you could elaborate on that in your answer, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $i$ you have
$$I_i \subset \sqrt{I_i^{n_i}} \subset \sqrt{ \sum_kI_k^{n_k}}$$
so that $\sqrt{ \sum_kI_k^{n_k}}$ contains all the $I_i$s. Hence it contains their sum.